# Failures tolerance in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to set for each stage how many failures I can tolerate when running a Spark job? For example, if I have 1000 nodes and I tolerate 10 failures, then in a case where 5 nodes have failed, my job will not rerun them and ignore their results.

As a a result, I will get a bit less accurate result, but such capability will haste the running time execution since I get a result with no need to wait for the failing nodes, assuming that their execution time is taking too long.

Thanks!

Comment: In the context of Hadoop, it is analogue to `mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
spark.speculation=true
```

This is from http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/configuration.html#scheduling

Which will use a heuristic to relaunch the task on another machine if one is clearly lagging.

Comment: The thing that I'm looking for is more delicate. I don't want to relaunch the task but I want to drop it. If in the end the number of failures did not exceeded a certain rate then the job succeeded. That way I give up on really hard nodes.